# "out the window" vs. "out of the window"

Tags: expressions, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between the expression "out the window" and "out of the window"?

I googled it but found conjectures of foreign speakers, only. One of the conjectures was that "out the window" is a shortened form of "out of the window", mainly used in Northern American English. Is that true?

In the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out) the following example sentence can be found:

> He leaned out the window.

On the other hand, I found this [sentence in a book](https://books.google.de/books?id=avha0yXMb3QC&pg=PT167&dq=%22out%20of%20the%20window%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxj9_DjpfpAhVRy6QKHe-RDIcQ6AEIUTAE#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20the%20window%22&f=false):

> Graham took off his gloves, leaned out of the window, and felt the stone below the sash.

Comment: There is a good discussion on "out the X" vs. "out of the X" over here: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3167. In your specific example, they mean the same thing and, I suspect, come down to personal preference. The link I've provided gives some examples where it's more natural to use "out **of** the X".

Comment: I (British, 60+) would always say 'out of the window' unless I was consciously speaking in a very informal register, and I find it quite surprising that Cambridge include 'out the window' in their examples.

Comment: It is a good idea to first search the ELL and ELU sites for similar questions. Do these help you? 1. [Use of expression “out of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233258/use-of-expression-out-of/233638#233638), 2.  [Are there any cases where “out of” is dead wrong or sounds awkward?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371809/are-there-any-cases-where-out-of-is-dead-wrong-or-sounds-awkward), and 3. [get out of the car vs get out the car](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150915/get-out-of-the-car-vs-get-out-the-car).

Answer (score 3):

As a native U.S. speaker, I see no difference.  I would call these 100% the same.

I feel this is simply evidence of an American, if not human, tendency to leave out what is not required while still bringing forth the meaning.  My ear would not react to either of these differently.  When speaking, I would regard "of" (in this case, not all cases) an unnecessary syllable, especially if speaking quickly.

My own example:

"Well, that idea is out the window." -- sounds more natural for me to say
"Well, that idea is out of the window." -- this sounds noticeably more stilted for me to say, like Sean Astin pronouncing po-ta-toes to Gollum in the *Lord of the Rings* movies.

But, for some reason, hearing another say either one doesn't sound much different, and certainly doesn't turn my head at all.